# Dúvida com edição de registro asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho a estrutura:

Página onde seleciono o registro para edição:

```html
            @if (Model.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.NOME</td>
                        <td>@item.LOGIN</td>
                        <td>@item.ADMINISTRADOR</td>
                        <td><a href="/CadastroUsuario/AlteraRegistro/@item.IDUSUARIO" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">ALTERAR</a></td>
                        <td><a href="/CadastroUsuario/ExcluirRegistro/@item.IDUSUARIO" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">EXCLUIR</a></td>
                    </tr>
                }

            }

        </div>
```

Recebe o id para pesquisar o registro:

```html
public ActionResult AlteraRegistro(int id)
        {
            if (Session["id"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            try
            {
                var tbuscar = new CadastroUsuarioAplicacao();
                tbuscar.ListarPorID(id);
                return View(tbuscar);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["Erro"] = "Erro ao Alterar Registro.";
                return RedirectToAction("ListarRegistro", "CadastroUsuario");
            }

        }
```

Código para fazer a consulta CadastroUsuarioAplicacao() :

```html
        public TB_USUARIO ListarPorID(int id)
        {
            var strQuery = string.Format("select * from tb_usuario where IDUSUARIO = '{0}' ", id);
            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader).FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }
```

Página para mostrar o registro para edição:

```html
   @model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }


    @Html.Partial("_navbarInterno")
    <br />
    @Html.Partial("_PartialMensagens")

    <br />
```

Tela de erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tbuscar.ListarPorID(id); ele retornar alguma coisa, já visto que não foi atribuido para nenhuma variavel?

Comment: sim, tem retorno, vou adicionar o código do CadastroUsuarioAplicacao

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO>` mude para `@model Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO` e na linha  
`tbuscar.ListarPorID(id)` coloque na frente um `TB_USUARIO us = tbuscar.ListarPorID(id)` e na `return View(tbuscar);` troque por `return  View(us);`

Comment: João, sua resposta está correta, pode postar a resposta para que possa marcar. Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: fiquei mais feliz por você resolver seus problemas já coloquei a resposta logo apago aqui e os outros comentários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelos comentários consegui enxergar os erros:

*Na sua View mude de:*

```
@model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO>
```

*para*

```
@model Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO
```

---

*No Controller* `AlteraRegistro` faça:

> na linha `tbuscar.ListarPorID(id)` coloque na frente um `TB_USUARIO us = tbuscar.ListarPorID(id);`;

---

> e na `return View(tbuscar);` troque por `return View(us);`

Comment: Fico muito feliz de encontrar pessoas que perdem alguns minutos do seu tempo para ajudar, são pessoas como você e tantos outros que fazem do stackoverflow um dos melhores sites para aprendizado e compartilhamento de conhecimento.

Comment: @itasouza vlw...

Answer (score 4):

A mensagem de erro está clara. Você está passando um objeto do tipo `CadastroUsuarioAplicacao` e em sua `View` você está esperando um `IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO>`.

Ou você altera a sua `View` para aceitar um `CadastroUsuarioAplicacao` ou passe um `IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO>` para a `View`.

Apenas para deixar mais claro, é nesta parte que você define o `Model` da View:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO>
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mais na minha página de listagem eu tenho : @model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO> é funciona normal. Por isso a dúvida.

Comment: eu já estou passando um IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO> para a View

Comment: Você está recebendo isso na View, mas em seu controller você está passando `CadastroUsuarioAplicacao` nesta parte: ` var tbuscar = new CadastroUsuarioAplicacao();
                tbuscar.ListarPorID(id);
                return View(tbuscar);`